# Yii2 framework Blank First Line in Response

Tags: yii2

I am using Yii2 framework, and trying to print raw text, but dunno why the text contain a empty line.
the code in Controller as below:

```
public function actionOnConnect(){
    $post_data = \Yii::$app->request->post();
    \Yii::getLogger()->log("--------->>> OnConnect!", Logger::LEVEL_INFO);
    \Yii::getLogger()->log($post_data, Logger::LEVEL_INFO);
    \Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    return '-->0';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Propably there's an space or enter character in your `/app/web/index.php` or in any config in `/app/config/yourconfigs.php`. Check files in `/app/config/` directory for unnecessary characters. (Of course directory `app` is for example).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have removed all comments in config files, but still cannot fix this issue.

Comment: Not comments, at beggining of the file, before `<?php` tag.

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the `actionOnConnect()` function?

Comment: I have show the code in my question :)

Comment: I have removed comment in the Controller file. Still same. sigh~

Comment: That's the function definition, not the function call.

Comment: This function is call from browser URL
http://host/live/on-connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Yii framework and fixed this issue.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBbni.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

probably ther is empty line in your code e.g.:

```
-line here    
<?php 
/* code/*
```

or:

```
/*code*/
?php>
-linehere
```